# JQuery Toggle visibility of divs

Tags: jquery

My theme uses the following structure (doesn't allow me to have a separate class for each button):

```
<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-1" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-1"><span>Button 1</span></button>

<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-2" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-2"><span>Button 2</span></button>
```

I am looking for some JQuery code which will toggle the visibility of two different divs, depending on which button the user presses.

i.e. If Button 1 is pressed the divs should be:

```
<div id="section-1" style="display:block;"></div>
<div id="section-2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and If Button 2 is pressed the divs should be:

```
<div id="section-1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="section-2" style="display:block;"></div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated as not sure how to start on this.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: This is super easy using `.hide()` and `.show()`. What issue are you facing while trying these methods?

Comment: I can't target the buttons as they have no class !

Comment: They have class `class="x-active"`

Comment: it's the same class for both though

Comment: Give them an `id` then and target them that way.

Comment: I can't give them an id nor a class, hence why i am asking this question

Comment: I can't edit the theme files in this scenario, and I can't change the markup

Comment: Then simply use `$('button').each()`.. what is the issue here?

Comment: how do I do that please? I only know the basics of JQuery :(

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Joanna: if you read the "*[ask]*" section, and then [edit] your question to show any attempts that you made to solve your problem, explain what you expected your code to do and how it failed then your question may be reopened and be available, and now useful, to other users in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// select all <button> elements, using the on() method
// to bind the anonymous function as the event-handler
// for the 'click' event:
$('button').on('click', function() {

  // here we find the attribute-value of the
  // data-x-toggleable attribute as a String,
  // and use the String.prototype.match() method
  // along with a regular expression, to find a
  // sequence of one-or-more numbers "\d+" at the
  // end of the string "$":
  const num = this.dataset.xToggleable.match(/\d+$/);

  // if match doesn't find a result then it returns
  // null; here we check that we have a result:
  if (num) {

    // if we have a result we hide all <div> elements
    // whose 'id' attribute-value starts with the string
    // of 'section', and then we hide them using the
    // hide() method:
    $('div[id^=section]').hide();

    // here we use a template literal string to interpolate
    // the value of the 'num' variable into the string,
    // which finds the <div> element with an 'id' of
    // "section" which ends with the number found earlier,
    // and we show it using the show() method:
    $(`div#section-${num}`).show();
  }
});
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const num = this.dataset.xToggleable.match(/\d+$/);
  if (num) {
    $('div[id^=section]').hide();
    $(`div#section-${num}`).show();
  }
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div[id^=section] {
  border: 2px solid #f90;
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
}

div[id^=section]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-1" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-1"><span>Button 1</span></button>

<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-2" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-2"><span>Button 2</span></button>

<div id="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2"></div>
```

As an alternative to jQuery the same thing can be easily accomplished with plain JavaScript:

```
// here we have a named function, defined using Arrow Syntax
// since we don't need to use the 'this' of the function; one
// argument, the Event object, is automatically passed in from
// EventTarget.addEventListener():
const toggleDisplay = (evt) => {

  // here we retrieve the element upon which the event-listener
  // was bound, using evt.currentTarget (the 'currentTarget'
  // property of the Event Object 'evt'), we then use the
  // Element.dataset API to access - as before - the sequence
  // of numbers at the end of the data-x-toggleable attribute-
  // value:
  const num = evt.currentTarget.dataset.xToggleable.match(/\d+$/);

  // if we have a matching number, therefore 'num' is not
  // false/falsey:
  if (num) {

    // we retrieve all <div> elements whose 'id' attribute-
    // value starts with "section" and then iterate over that
    // NodeList using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
    document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=section]').forEach(

      // the first argument to the anonymous Arrow function
      // expression is a reference to the current Node of the
      // NodeList over which we're iterating, here I called
      // id 'div', but you can call it anything you like (so
      // long as it's not a reserved word); in this function
      // we hide the elements by updating the 'display' property
      // of the 'style' to 'none':
      (div) => div.style.display = 'none'
    );

    // because we're using an id selector, again using a
    // template literal (as in the jQuery example), we 
    // can only retrieve one element (if there's a match)
    // or null if no element is found. As we can only find
    // one element we can update its display to 'block' to
    // in order to show it:
    document.querySelector(`#section-${num}`).style.display = 'block';
  }
};

// here we find all the <button> elements on the page,
// using document.querySelectorAll() and then use
// NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over those
// element-nodes using another Arrow function expression:
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(

  // the first argument represents the current node of
  // the nodeList, here called 'btn'; with the arrow
  // function we bind the toggleDisplay() function, note
  // the deliberate lack of parentheses, as the event-
  // handler for clicks on the <button> elements:
  (btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay)
);
```

```js
const toggleDisplay = (evt) => {
  const num = evt.currentTarget.dataset.xToggleable.match(/\d+$/);
  if (num) {
    document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=section]').forEach(
      (div) => div.style.display = 'none'
    );
    document.querySelector(`#section-${num}`).style.display = 'block';
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(
  (btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div[id^=section] {
  border: 2px solid #f90;
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
}

div[id^=section]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-1" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-1"><span>Button 1</span></button>

<button class="x-active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-2" data-x-toggle="tab" data-x-toggleable="tab-item-2"><span>Button 2</span></button>

<div id="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2"></div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [attribute-starts-with (`[attr^="value"]`) selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- jQuery:

  - [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Here Sir, take an upvote. But still. Stop using jQuery ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, and - since you insisted - there's also a plain JS version now.

Comment: Haha. That's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// For all .x-active buttons, add a click listener calling the 
// toggleActive function with the button's aria-controls attribute
document.querySelectorAll('.x-active').forEach( 
   btn => btn.addEventListener( 'click', () => 
      toggleActive(btn.dataset.ariaControls)
   )
);

// For all sections, check if the id is equal to the target provided,
// which is again the aria controls attribute of the button
const toggleActive = function( target ) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.section').forEach( sect =>
    sect.style.display = target === sect.id ? 'block' : 'none';
  );
}
```

Note that aria-controls attribute doesn't match the ids on your sections. That needs to be fixed for the code to work. Also, you will need to add the .section class to all sections.

Also Note: Throw away jQuery. Please. You can easily translate the methods above to jQuery if you like but as you see - no need to use jQuery.